# Knime JSON transformer - Adding an attribute to a JSON object

Tags: json, knime

I have converted some columns to JSON using the `columns to json` node. The output from that is:

```
{
  "Material" : 101,
  "UOM" : "GRAM",
  "EAN" : 7698,
  "Description" : "CHALK BOX"
}
```

I would like to add the value of the `material` property as a key to each JSON object. So, my desired output is:

```
"101":    {
      "Material" : 101,
      "UOM" : "GRAM",
      "EAN" : 7698,
      "Description" : "CHALK BOX"
    }
```

I have tried entering the following expression in the `JSON transformer` node but all I get is a question mark in the new column it generates:

```
$Material$:{"Material":$Material$,"UOM":$UOM$,"EAN":$EAN$,"Description":$Description$}
```

I have also tried replacing the `$Material$` with "Material" but got the same result.

How would I go about this, please?

Comment: Did you keep the original columns too? What is the name of the JSON column?

Comment: Yes . It's jsondata

Answer (score 1):

In case you convert the `Material` column to `String` (for example with `String Manipulator`), you can easily configure the `Columns to JSON`:

[image: Columns to JSON with Data bound key for String Material and not including that]

As you can see the `Data bound key` is the important part.

The `String Manipulator` node configuration (`string($Material$)`):

[image: string($Material$)]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Gabor. I tried this but in the columns to json dialog where you select the columns you want, the column containing the material value kept defaulting to the bottom of the list no matter what i tried ! I could not reorder the columns the way i wanted. How would i solve this? cheers

Comment: Could you add a (few) screenshot(s) to your question, I am not sure what exactly is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve this by a different method.

I split the JSON data into several columns, then used the `join` function to create a string in the required order. I put the resulting string through the `string to JSON` node to create the new JSON object.

Thanks for all your tips and comments !